# Check if a PaypalTransactionID is valid (express checkout)

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am using Express Checkout. The DoExpressCheckoutPayment method completes the payment and returns a TransactionID. 
I am using this transactionID in a web service. Is there a way to check if a transactionID is valid or belongs to a completed payment?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure what you are asking, if you receive a transaction id + details the transaction is completed.

Answer (score 0):

If the call is successful and you get a transaction ID then that's a valid ID.  Not sure why you would think it's not..??  You could also make a call to [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) using that transaction ID just to confirm you get data back.